# Handling file upload and resizing image with Unisharp Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, unisharp-file-manager

I am using Unisharp file upload for my laravel project. The package working properly. Now what I want is, I want to have array of file type like:

```
[name] => MyFile.jpg      
[type] => image/jpeg
[tmp_name] => /tmp/php/php6hst32
[error] => UPLOAD_ERR_OK
[size] => 98174
```

of the image URL of Unisharp filemanager. Suppose if I select `http://example.com/storage/files/42/lace-up.png` from Unisharp filemanager I want to get file array like above.

I want to have this because I want to resize the images accordingly and store them to different folders.

I have created following function to upload and resize images:

```
function uploadImage($file, $dir, $thumb_dimension=null){

  $path = public_path().'/uploads/'.$dir;

  if(!File::exists($path)){
      File::makeDirectory($path, 0777, true, true);
  }

  $file_name = ucfirst($dir).'-'.date('Ymdhis').rand(0,999).".".$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
  $success = $file->move($path, $file_name);
  if($success){
      $file_path = $path.'/'.$file_name;
      if($thumb_dimension){
          list($width,$height) = explode('x',$thumb_dimension);
          Image::make($file_path)->resize($width,$height, function($const){
              $const->aspectRatio();
          })->save($path.'/Thumb-'.$file_name);
      }
      return $file_name;
  } else {
      return null;
  }
}
```

Is it possible?

**Edit**

I want to use the following function after getting details of image.

```
function uploadImage($file, $dir, $thumb_dimension=null){

  $path = public_path().'/uploads/'.$dir;

  if(!File::exists($path)){
      File::makeDirectory($path, 0777, true, true);
  }
  
  $file_name = ucfirst($dir).'-'.date('Ymdhis').rand(0,999).".".$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
  $success = $file->move($path, $file_name);
  if($success){
      $file_path = $path.'/'.$file_name;
      if($thumb_dimension){
          list($width,$height) = explode('x',$thumb_dimension);
          Image::make($file_path)->resize($width,$height, function($const){
              $const->aspectRatio();
          })->save($path.'/Thumb-'.$file_name);
      }
      return $file_name;
  } else {
      return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: so basically you want to extract details of file attached in that link

Comment: @bhucho Yes because I want to store images to another folder.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just extract image from the link, you just need to create a small function to handle it.

```
public function getImageViaLink($link){
    try {
        $info = pathinfo($link);
        $image = file_get_contents($link);
        $arr['basename'] = $info['basename'];
        $file_info = new \finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
        $mime_type = $file_info->buffer($image);
        $arr['size'] = strlen($image);
        $arr['mime_type'] = $mime_type;
        $path = public_path() .'/'. $arr['basename'];
        
        // You can save contents of link in your file directly or store it in tmp
        file_put_contents($path, $image);
        $arr['path'] = $path;
        return $arr;
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
        
}
```

As for the case of `error` in your array, you basically want [file upload errors](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php) but it can easily be handled by Exception.

As a sidenote, if you have the request variable at the time of storing image using unisharp, you can access all these details in $request.

```
// dd() of a request containing image file.
array:2 [▼
  "_token" => "e7v7ZxaKoIFGIYOscCAFwsoB8olw8lrNjwx8Azyi"
  "attachment_1_0" => UploadedFile {#229 ▼
    -test: false
    -originalName: "db.png"
    -mimeType: "image/png"
    -size: 86110
    -error: 0
     path: "C:\xampp\tmp"
     filename: "phpF4F4.tmp"
     basename: "phpF4F4.tmp"
     pathname: "C:\xampp\tmp\phpF4F4.tmp"
     extension: "tmp"
     realPath: "C:\xampp\tmp\phpF4F4.tmp" 
    
 ... and many more
```

You can create a listener that whenever an image is stored you can create another copy with all the details to save it to another location.

Comment: Thanks, Bhuco. I am not uploading from Unisharp. I am trying to access the images that are already been uploaded from Unisharp.

Comment: so you can access the image details stored in the link using getImageViaLink, whats the issue